# getting this error while learning to get the future request from jasonplaceholder

Tags: flutter, jsonplaceholder

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
"\n\n\n  <!--\n    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the\n    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.\n\n    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for\n    it to work correctly.\n\n    For more details:\n    * [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base\n\n](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base%5Cn%5Cn)    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of\n    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.\n  -->\n  <base href="/">\n\n  <meta charset="UTF-8">\n  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">\n  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">\n\n  \n  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">\n  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">\n  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="flutter_application_1">\n  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">\n\n  \n  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>\n\n  flutter_application_1\n  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">\n\n  \n    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.\n    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;\n  \n  \n  <script src="flutter.js" defer>\n\n\n  \n    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {\n      // Download main.dart.js\n      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({\n        serviceWorker: {\n          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,\n        }\n      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {\n        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();\n      }).then(function(appRunner) {\n        return appRunner.runApp();\n      });\n    });\n  \n\n\n"

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class JasonParsingSimple extends StatefulWidget {
  const JasonParsingSimple({super.key});

  @override
  State<JasonParsingSimple> createState() => _JasonParsingSimpleState();
}

class _JasonParsingSimpleState extends State<JasonParsingSimple> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Future data;
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    data = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Parsing Jason"),
      ),
      // body: Center(
      //     child: Container(
      //   child: FutureBuilder(
      //       future: getData(),
      //       builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
      //         return Text(snapshot.data[0]['title']);
      //       }),
      // )),
    );
  }

  Future getData() async {
    var data;
    String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    Network network = Network(url);

    data = network.fetchData();

    // data.then((value) {
    //   print(value[3]);
    // });

    return data;
  }
}

class Network {
  final String url;

  Network(this.url);

  Future fetchData() async {
    print("$url");

    Response response = await get(Uri.parse("url"));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(json.encode(response.body));
      return json.encode(response.body);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this,

```dart
 Response response = await get(Uri.parse("url"));
```

write like this,

```dart
 Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
```

**cause:** `url` is a property of `Network` class, this property actually holds the url address you assign from `getData()` function. But `"url"` is nothing but a string holds the value `"url"`.